# Snowflake order by

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way I can select from a table without specifying the order by column in the order by clause?

select col1 from table order by col2

This works in TSQL, but doesn't appear to be allowed in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab AS 
SELECT 1 AS col1, 'B' AS col2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A';

SELECT col1
FROM tab
ORDER BY col2;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  is 'tab' a temporary table or will I have to explicitly drop it?

Comment: @Stephen In this example it is a permanent table. `CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE` will create temporary table that exists as long as session is active